# Find string in NodeSet with XPath (Nokgiri)

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE pdf2xml SYSTEM "pdf2xml.dtd">

<pdf2xml>
    <page number="1">
        <text top="91">Rapport</text>
        <text top="102">foo</text>
    </page>
    <page number="2">
        <text top="91">Rapport</text>
        <text top="102">bar</text>
    </page>
    <page number="3">
        <text top="91">Rapport</text>
        <text top="102">asdf</text>
    </page>
</pdf2xml>
```

which I'm doing this with:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("file.xml"))
pages = doc.xpath("//page")
nodeset = pages[0].xpath("./text") + pages[1].xpath("./text")
```

I want to find a node by string in nodeset, like this

```
irb(main):011:0> nodeset.at_xpath("//text[text()[contains(., 'bar')]]")
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fea6a4821d4 name="text" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fea6a482170 name="top" value="102">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fea6a481cac "bar">]>
```

but I don't want to use `//`

I have managed to do this

```
irb(main):018:0> nodeset.at_xpath("text()[contains(., 'bar')]")
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fea6a481cac "bar">
```

but I want the whole `<text>` node.

What should my xpath query on nodeset look like?

Comment: As soon as I had finished writing my question it struck me: I can do `nodeset.at_xpath("text()[contains(., 'bar')]").parent` to get the `<text>` node. Still curious though to find out how to do it in xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For selecting parent of the current node you can use `..` For example,

```
/pdf2xml/page[1]
```

points to the first `<page>` node. If you want to select its parent again you can write

```
/pdf2xml/page[1]/..
```

This will select `<pdf2xml>` node which is the parent of `<page>`.

On the similar lines you can use `..` for selecting `parent` node in your example.

For more information you can refer [**this**](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right, `nodeset.at_xpath("text()[contains(., 'bar')]/..")` is what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simpler than selecting the `text()` node and then selecting the parent node is to just select the node you want in the first place:

```
pages = doc.xpath("//page")
puts pages.xpath("text[contains(.,'bar')]")
#=> <text top="102">bar</text>
```

If it makes you feel better, you could alternatively explicitly test the `text()` child node of the `text` element instead of using the text equivalent for the element:

```
pages.xpath("text[contains(text(),'bar')]")
```

Comment: In my case, I don't want to do a query on `pages`, I want to do a query on `nodeset` (which contains a subset of `<text>` nodes from `pages`). Maybe I should have been more explicit in my question, but I'm sure others may benefit from this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that

```
nodeset.at_xpath("../text[text()[contains(., 'bar')]]")
```

works too.

Edit: But I think this is slower than `/..`.